# Regarding Raspberry Pi Zero W - USB Access from GPIO Header

Tags: raspberry-pi, usb

I am using Raspberry Pi Zero W for my project. I want to use GPIO Pins as USB instead of the on-bard MicroUSB connector. Is it possible?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry, the GPIO connector does not include any USB signals.
There are some USB hubs that connect to the test pads on the back side of the zero, e.g this one sold by Adafruit: https://www.adafruit.com/product/3298

If you are happy with just one USB port but don't like the micro connector, you could probably solder your own connector with a short pigtail lead to the same test points.

You can't use the micro usb connector at the same time as a hub or usb connector attached to the test pads as they are the same signals as in the micro connector.

The test pads p22 and p23 can be seen in this schematic:

https://github.com/raspberrypi/documentation/blob/master/hardware/raspberrypi/schematics/Raspberry-Pi-Zero-V1.3-Schematics.pdf

Comment: Thanks very much. Using the Test Pads my problem can be solved. Thanks again. Regards.